# Methods to wait until DC is fully booted in order to add another server as DC to that domain?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to create a PowerShell script which is capable of automatically creating Hyper-V VMs, configuring them and installing a AD domain.

Infrastructure: the script is creating 3 VMs: 2x Server 2016 Core (meant for the DCs) and 1x Windows 10 Pro

After creating a new forest with `Install-ADDSForest`. DC1 will automatically reboot. Directly after that DC2 is trying to execute `Install-ADDSDomainController` which is failing because it can't contact the domain, because something on DC1 isn't ready.

I've already tried to wait for PowerShell Direct & gpsvc (because the shell is showing "Waiting for gpsvc" for a long time.). I've also tried to ping the domain name and execute `Install-ADDSDomainController` after ICMP reply.

Now to my question: What service needs to be running in order to add the other server as a DC?
I would then get the status of that service and continue my script if that named service is running.

I would also appreciate if someone could provide a different/better solution!

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I've found somewhat of a solution for my case:
I'm now catching the error with `try catch` inside a `do while` loop.

Comment: Do you have snippets of your script as examples? How are you calling `Install-ADDSDomainController`?

Comment: @RileyCarney I'm calling `Invoke-Command` on DC2 (which is working). Inside the `-ScriptBlock` I'm calling `Install-ADDSDomainController -DomainName $domain -Credential $dom_creds -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $pw -InstallDNS -Force`  this is working as expected. If I execute that snipped manually it is working, but only a few seconds later after I can login to DC1.